# SSE2 value extraction problem

Tags: c, inline-assembly, sse, intrinsics

i want to extract the value(first word 16bits) from 128bit register, i got this command but this is not working.there will be some arithmetic operation after setting the value of a, than there will be some arithmetic operation as result inside the variable will change    finally i want extract the first word...how can i do this...

```
int r;
int inm=0;

__m128i a=_mm_setr_epi16(8,9,3,2,4,5,6,11);

_asm{
    r = _mm_extract_epi16(a,inm);    
}
```

Comment: How is that JavaScript? Your code looks like C. Besides that, you shouldn't mark questions here as urgent.

Answer (score 8):

You don't put intrinsics inside an _asm block.  They behave just like any other function.  This will work fine:

```
#include <emmintrin.h>

__m128i a = _mm_setr_epi16(8,9,3,2,4,5,6,11);
int r = _mm_extract_epi16(a, 0);
```

Answer (score 6):

The `pextrw` instruction does only work with an immediate value. In C this means the value needs to be a compile time constant.

```
int r;
static const int inm=0;

__m128i a=_mm_setr_epi16(8,9,3,2,4,5,6,11);

r = _mm_extract_epi16(a,inm);
```